# Hibernate Search + Lucene: Fallback-search for stop words

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

I use Hibernate Search in version 5.11.5 together with Apache Lucene 5.5.5. In my example I use the `StopFilterFactory` with the default stop word set defined in `StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET` (so e.g. "this", "will", "be", ...).

Now I index three music song titles: "I will survive", "we will rock you", "this will be"

My search query is "Rock will make me survive". So I find "I will *survive*" and "we will *rock* you", but not "this will be", because this song consists completely of stop words. If I search for "this will be", then I find nothing.

Now I need a "fallback" search for these songs: If and only if a song title consists completely of stop words, then I would like to find them if all words are contained in my search string. So searching for "I will be a fireman" does not find "this will be", but searching for "I *will be* like *this*" finds "this will be".

Do you know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, in such a situation I would consider simply doing away with `StopFilterFactory`.

The main problem with stop words is that they appear very frequently in many documents, and thus they affect the relevance (score) in a way that's completely out of proportion considering they don't have much meaning.

So we generally don't index them at all, to work around the problem. As a bonus, this may reduce the index size to some extent.

But there's another solution, which is to keep stop words and fix how scores are computed. In Lucene, the component responsible for computing scores is called the `Similarity`. The default one in Hibernate Search 5 / Lucene 5.5 is `ClassicSimilarity`, which suffers from this problem with stop words. Another more recent implementation is BM25, and that implementation has much better behavior when it comes to stop words: it does not let them affect the score as much. You can find an in-depth explanation [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/practical-bm25-part-2-the-bm25-algorithm-and-its-variables), if you are interested. Note that BM25 replaced `ClassicSimilarity` as the default similarity in more recent versions of Lucene and Hibernate Search, as well as in Elasticsearch.

I'd suggest you [change the Similarity](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-similarity) to use `org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.BM25Similarity`, remove your stop-word filters, then reindex your data, then test your queries again. Are you getting relevant hits near the top? Is the index size still manageable? Is your query "this will be" matching something? If so, switching to BM25 is a completely viable solution.

Note that you can also consider upgrading to [Hibernate Search 6](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/) which uses BM25 by default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already use this similarity. But in my special case I have a custom stop word list and sometimes indexed words which consist 95% of stop words and I still *must* find them if I search for the single non-stopword. Is there a possibility to register a custom list of words which do not affect the score?

Comment: @Rokko_11 I'm not following; are you saying that searching for a non-stopword doesn't yield the correct hits? That seems odd, I must have misunderstood. Could you explain the undesirable effect of indexing the stopwords, perhaps with an example?

Comment: No, searching for non-stopwords is working at the moment, but if I remove the StopFilter the score is lower than before. I filter search results with a very low score, so I would loose some search results... But thank you, I rethink your solution.